# How to delete previous lines to the one found in grep in shell script

Tags: sh

I want to write a shell script code with a file having these values in file

```
test.txt --> file
```

```
sample
#comment
jacuzzi
#comment
testing
it was the the age of wisdom4,
```

So, first I want to grep the line which starts with "te" , and then delete previous 4 lines to it, but only if those lines starts with "#"

like, the output should be
sample
jacuzzi
testing
it was the the age of wisdom4,

I wrote this command using awk

```
awk 'NR==FNR{if (/^te.*/) for (i=-4;i<=0;i++) if (what to write here?) del[NR+i]; next} !(FNR in del)' test.txt
```

Can someone help me with this if condition? so that it can read the previous 4 lines and delete them only if that contains #

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this can help you.

techeck=`cat 2.txt|grep ^'te'|wc -l` && if [ $techeck -ge 1 ] ; then cat 2.txt|grep -v ^'#'; fi